# Macbook Pro 13-inch stuck at Gray screen with apple logo and wheel

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a 13 inch Macbook Pro, early 2011 with its original OS.
I came to a point where its battery needs to be replaced, and I can't use it without using its charger/adapter. One time, I  accidentally  pulled out the charger and it turned off. It was not my first time so I just didn't worry. But when I plugged it back and turned on the laptop, it just got stuck at the gray screen with the Apple logo, the wheel, and a loading bar. At first I thought I should just wait, but later I realized it's still stuck for almost an hour!

I tried to Google and I read that something is corrupt.

I don't really have too important files, so it's okay if I would need to reinstall the OS. Or do I need to change the laptop's hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Well, seeing as the laptop is at least attempting to boot from the hard drive, I'd say that your hard drive is fine.

My recommendation is that you reinstall Mac OS X. An early 2011 MacBook Pro would've come with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, so you should have had some DVDs come with the MacBook Pro when you bought it. Use those to re-install Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: I checked the box when I bought it, but I found no discs. It's either I lost it or it really didn't come with one. I can buy it, but are you sure reinstalling it will solve my problem?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6 is no longer for sale at Apple. Re-installing is very likely to solve the issue, but there is a possibility that you have a faulty hard drive. If your computer is displaying the grey Apple logo + spinning pinwheel, then it's reading from the hard drive, which makes the possibility of the hard drive being the problem very unlikely.

Comment: But I think it's downloadable online, for free. If I use a USB/flash drive with the OS X 10.6, will that be fine?

Comment: By the way, I tried to Safe Boot, and it says "The Volume Macintosh HD could not be repaired."

Comment: It's not free. Mavericks and Yosemite are (10.9 and 10.10 respectively). If you repartition the drive using Disk Utility when you are able to boot from some form of recovery media, the errors should vanish.

Comment: Will it be fine if I use OS X Lion? I'm planning to create a bootable flash drive with it.

Comment: OS X Lion will be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Apple has issued a Repair Extension Program for Video Issues. I was experiencing the same problem and had tired several solutions that worked for a short period of time, but ultimately I was unable to get my MBP up and running last night and brought it into an Apple store. They determined that my issues was in fact a video issue and qualified for free service.

If you purchased a MBP between February 2011 and December 2013 and suspect that your MBP is experiencing the same issue, then check out the page URL above to see if your MBP qualifies for service.

Here's an excerpt from the page

=========

Apple has determined that a small percentage of MacBook Pro systems may exhibit distorted video, no video, or unexpected system restarts. These MacBook Pro systems were sold between February 2011 and December 2013.

Apple or an Apple Authorized Service Provider will repair affected MacBook Pro systems, free of charge. See below for details on affected models and service options.

Symptoms

An affected MacBook Pro may display one or more of the following symptoms:

Distorted or scrambled video on the computer screen No video on the computer screen (or external display) even though the computer is on Computer restarts unexpectedly

Products affected 15-inch and 17-inch MacBook Pro models manufactured in 2011 15-inch MacBook Pro with Retina models manufactured from Mid 2012 to Early 2013

Answer (score -1):

for anyone having this problem its 100 percent working ok i have the problem and i did solve it don't u lsn to anyone don't do anything with the software "if you don't have any hard drive problems existed on the disk management " then try this option open ur laptop take off the battery and take off the hard disk press 10 sec on the power button then re instal the hard disk and do press the power button for another 10 second after that insert the battery and turn it on :)

Comment: Your answer might be easier to read (and follow) if you could break it down into stepwise instructions. Also more detailed instructions on how to open a Macbook Pro and where the battery and the hard disk are located inside the case would be helpful.